# With Witch Doctor Mass Confusion, do elite affixes still affect you?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

When using the Witch Doctor "[mass confusion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/mass-confusion)" ability, it is possible to confuse elites into fighting on your side.  Many of them have AoE affixes like fire chains, arcane enchantment, mortar, etc.  I see the elites continue to use them even when confused, but there is so much chaos I can't really tell if I'm getting hurt by the ones that are confused.  It doesn't matter too much at my current level, but will start to matter more as I level up.  Do the AoE affixes of "confused" elites still hurt you?  If not, do they start hurting immediately after confusion wears off, or do they have to be *reactivated*.

Comment: Is this directed for the inferno difficulty, or all difficulties? I see you mention "as I level up", so I assume you are not level 60 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have read multiple forms on battle.net ([here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5573702981) and [here](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/63484-spell-mass-confusion/)) as well as tested this ability with my lvl 60 witch doctor in inferno.

My findings so far:

- Elites can be confused into fighting for you (which you mentioned)
- The AoE affixes (fire chain, arcane, mortar) of the confused enemies *do* still hurt you.
- The only bonus you gain from confusing an elite is its basic, monster specific attack for the time you have it confused.
- As the difficulty increases in the game (hell and beyond) the time you control an elite decreases (to about 2-3 seconds) and the chance to control them becomes harder. This is intentional to keep the CC (crowd control) abilities from being overpowered late in the game.

The only thing I am unsure about is whether of not the affixes reset after being stunned or confused. From what I remember, they do not, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the research, much appreciated.  The char I'm using is not level 60 yet, but my main is.  I think this topic will be somewhat interesting to folks that use the enchantress as well, since I think her "mass confusion" ability is essentially the same as the WD.